# Hackintosh Workstation build suggestions

Tags: compatibility

so I'm in the process of building this Hackintosh workstation and I'm going to dual boot it with Windows 10 and Mac(El Capitan) can someone tell me if these parts are compatible or what I would have to do to make them compatible.

Parts:

CPU: Intel Xeon E5-2620 V3 2.4GHz 6-Core Processor

Motherboard: MSI X99A GAMING 7 ATX LGA2011-3 Motherboard

Memory: G.Skill Ripjaws 4 series 64GB (8 x 8GB) DDR4-2400 Memory

Storage: 2x Samsung SSD 850 PRO 2.5" SATA III 512

GPU: NVIDIA Quadro M4000 8GB Video Card

Wireless Network Adapter: Asus PCE-AC68 802.11a/b/g/n/ac PCI-Express x1 Wi-Fi 
Adapter

Case: NZXT H440 (Black/Red) ATX Mid Tower Case

Power Supply: Thermaltake 750W 80+ Gold Certified Semi-Modular ATX Power Supply

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about compatibility are off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work perfectly except you should note that you cannot install Windows based drivers on a Mac which means that some of the more advanced functionality on some components cannot be used.